# Select array value and save works in admin, not at frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a plugin which have wishlist and where the admin or the customer themself may fill the fields for the wishlist profile.

Later on we added a few custom fields on a custom made plugin, and made one of the fields a select for several `$stores` to chose from.

The first block in the code-snippet hold the array and the field.

```
$stores = array(
"name0" => "chose store",
"name1" => "store 1",
        );


    $fields[ 'nmgr_butik' ] = array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'options' => $stores,
        'label' => __( 'Butik', 'my-text-domain' ), // change 'my-text-domain' to your text domain.
        'placeholder' => __( 'Butik', 'my-text-domain' ),
        'required' => false, // remove this or set it to false if the field is not required
        'fieldset' => 'profile', // this makes the field appear among the profile fields
        'value' => get_post_meta( $args[ 'wishlist' ]->get_id(), 'nmgr_butik', true ),
        'priority' => '11',
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'nmgr_fields', 'my_nmgr_add_butik_field', 10, 2 );
```

and when saving the value

```
function save_backend_data($extra_data, $wishlist) {
    $wishlist_id = get_the_ID(); // Get the wishlist ID directly from the $wishlist object
    if ($wishlist_id) {
        update_post_meta($wishlist_id, 'nmgr_butik', $_POST["nmgr_butik"]);
        }
}

add_action('nmgr_save_extra_data', 'save_backend_data', 10, 2);
```

this example works perfectly using the admin, chosing a store and save it.

But I also want to sort so the select also works with frontend. It does display the saved value, but seem not to save the value i change to.

I have tried making a second function like a frontend save.

```
function save_frontend_data($wishlist) {
    $wishlist_id = $wishlist->get_id();
    
    if ($wishlist_id) {
        $selected_butik = sanitize_text_field($_POST['nmgr_butik']);
        update_post_meta($wishlist_id, 'nmgr_butik', $selected_butik);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'save_frontend_data', 10, 1);
```

Still the value is the old one when refreshing the browser.